# Drupal 7 Theme switching and content relevence

Tags: drupal, themes

I'm building a Drupal site, which has 4 different themes with different theme templates.

I need to use the same Drupal database to control all the content for all 4 themes.

I setup taxonomy for each theme, so when I create content I can apply it to one of the four different themes.

The Urls need to look something like

mysite.com/theme1/node/21

And

mysite.com/theme2/node/2

Also I need to make sure

mysite.com/theme1 needs to bring up the page-front.tpl.php for that theme based on the URL

I've tried using themekey which works ok except I don't then know how to pull only content which has the applied taxonomy term for that site.

and I can't get it to work with something like this

mysite.com/theme2/node/1

Only for

mysite.com/node/1/theme2

Any ideas, or anything you can provide to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a ton of ways to do this but this is how I would do it.

- Create a view display with an argument that filters by taxnonomy term translated from name to tid. This view will work as the front page.
- Also create a view display that takes two arguments, checking if the second argument is a node tagged with the first arguments taxonomy term name. If it's not return not found.
- Note, we will only access these views in code so it doesnt matter if they are pages or blocks. Make sure not to name them the same as the themes if they are pages though, then they will override our menu entries.

You could also query stuff just like in node.module but personally I prefer using views for doing the filtering.

There might be typos and whatnot in this snippet but nothing I can see now.

A good resource: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 *
 * Here we define the new frontpages as well as a node view page for all them custom themes.
 */
function example_menu() {
  $items = array();
  foreach (example_custom_themes() as $theme) {
    // Define the front page
    $items[$theme] = array(
      'page callback' => 'views_embed_view',
      'page arguments' => array('VIEW', 'DISPLAY', $theme), // The front page view
      'access arguments' => array('access content'),
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      'theme callback' => 'example_theme_callback',
      'theme arguments' => array($theme),
    );
    // Define the node views
    $items[$theme . '/node/%node'] = array(
      'title callback' => 'node_page_title', 
      'title arguments' => array(1),
      'page callback' => 'views_embed_view',
      'page arguments' => array('VIEW', 'DISPLAY', $theme, 1), // The node view display
      'access callback' => 'node_access', 
      'access arguments' => array('view', 1),
      'theme callback' => 'example_theme_callback',
      'theme arguments' => array($theme),
    );
  }
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Returns an array of the machine named custom themes.
 */
function example_custom_themes() {
  return array('theme1', 'theme2');
}

/**
 * Does nothing but return the theme name
 */
function example_theme_callback($theme) {
  return $theme;
}

/**
 * Check if the url matches the front page of a theme. If so, suggest front template.
 */
function example_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (in_array(arg(0), example_custom_themes()) && is_null(arg(1))) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = 'page__front';
  }
}
```